# What are the implications of not using padding with AES?

Tags: cryptography, aes

I have some problem with padding when working with AES algorithm, so what happens if I disable padding checking when encrypting and decrypting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES is a block cipher and only operates on a single block. It needs a mode of operation to encrypt more than one block. If the mode of operation also works only on blocks (like CBC, ECB) then you can't encrypt arbitrary plaintexts. If you disable padding for those modes, you will need to supply plaintexts that are exactly a multiple of the block size (128-bit for AES).

This is not necessary for modes like CTR or GCM which are streaming modes. They don't require/support padding.

If for some reason, you're not able to make the default PKCS#5/PKCS#7 padding work, you can opt for a ZeroPadding which appends only 0x00 bytes to the plaintext up until a multiple of the block size is reached. This has the implication that the original plaintext cannot end with 0x00 bytes, because they would be removed during decryption. You can of course use any type of filler byte as long as it is not possible for it to appear in the plaintext at the end.

Comment: The presence of padding allows the decryption end to detect a faulty decryption, and flag an error - only certain final bytes are allowed after decrypting.  In the absence of padding this check is not possible, so your decrypted file might be garbage (e.g. decrypted with the wrong key).  You will need to make a separate sanity-check on the file if you don't use padding.

Comment: @rossum That's very true, but there is still roughly a 1 in 256 chance that the padding matches. Also, some bad implementations simply don't verify the PKCS#7 padding, but just use the last byte to remove the padding. In any case, one should not use padding to verify the validity of the plaintext/ciphertext. Instead using an authenticated mode of operation like GCM/EAX or encrypt-then-MAC. (I didn't want to drift too much into the realm of [crypto.se])